# check current user has access to database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I log into mysql as root and run

```
GRANT SELECT (`creator`, `name`, `disguise`), SHOW VIEW ON `kit` TO 'ssc'@'localhost';
```

Now from my code I log in as `'ssc'@'localhost'`.

```
Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(..., 'ssc', ...);
```

How can the user `'ssc'@'localhost'` check that it has the above grant?

I am thinking maybe I can execute some queries in a `try` / `catch (SQLException)` block, but perhaps there's a more elegant way.

Also if I am to take that approach I don't know what queries would be the most appropriate (fastest, least intensive).

Comment: Testing the operation you want to perform is probably the most reliable. Testing the `GRANT` rules may not be sufficient as you could misunderstand them.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can parse the SHOW GRANT query. here is the reference.
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html
2. you can query the information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES table. here is the reference.
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-privileges-table.html

Comment: So just query `SHOW GRANTS` and parse the result?

Comment: @minseong you can specify the user by SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ssc'@'localhost'; It returns all grants of the user. so you need to parse the results. by second method, you can specify the user, database and priviege type.